# When should you not use allow-cross-orgin?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http-headers, cross-domain

I've recently been using JavaScript to take my email's RSS and phrase it into a neat little app, and I've even set up a few tests on my local server and done some Cross origin (localhost and local IP etc.) to experiment to see what all can be done.

**However,** when I tried it for the first time I forgot to send a cross origin header, this made me wonder, **why.** I didn't see a reason why not to send a cross origin header for every page, although, it seemed a waste for bandwidth maybe. So, **when should I (or others) avoid using:**

```
   header("access-control-allow-origin: *")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that it will also allow bad people to 'fake' that they are local on your server in some instances. Secure coding can block most methods the bad people use - you are essentially just leaving the door unlocked but still setting the alarm.

Comment: I had thought there would be more activity on this topic. I do finally see what you mean, so it's okay for most things, like if I was making a RSS feed it would be great, but if I am making a bank login screen or something like that it wouldn't be a good idea.